# Parse Profile Image Trouble

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

Here's my code:

```
@IBAction func setPicture(sender: UIButton) {
    var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    imagePicker.delegate = self

    let profileImage: PFFile = user["profileImage"] as! PFFile

    profileImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    if error == nil {
    let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)!
    self.profileImageView.image = image
        }
    }


    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The error is on the let profileImage: PFFile = user["profileImage"] line. It won't build because of user. Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think it may works for you.

```
@IBAction func setPicture(sender: UIButton) {
    var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
imagePicker.delegate = self

    //getting the current user
    var user = PFUser.currentUser();

    let profileImage: PFFile = user["profileImage"] as! PFFile

    profileImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

      if error == nil {
        let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)!
        self.profileImageView.image = image
      }
    }

    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```